# How to get feature Importance in naive bayes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I have a dataset of reviews which has a class label of positive/negative. I am applying Naive Bayes to that reviews dataset. Firstly, I am converting into Bag of words. Here **sorted_data['Text']** is reviews and **final_counts is a sparse matrix**

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer() 
final_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(sorted_data['Text'].values)
```

I am splitting the data into train and test dataset.

```
X_1, X_test, y_1, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(final_counts, labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
```

I am applying the naive bayes algorithm as follows

```
optimal_alpha = 1
NB_optimal = BernoulliNB(alpha=optimal_aplha)

# fitting the model
NB_optimal.fit(X_tr, y_tr)

# predict the response
pred = NB_optimal.predict(X_test)

# evaluate accuracy
acc = accuracy_score(y_test, pred) * 100
print('\nThe accuracy of the NB classifier for k = %d is %f%%' % (optimal_aplha, acc))
```

Here X_test is test dataset in which pred variable gives us whether the vector in X_test is positive or negative class.

**The X_test shape is (54626 rows, 82343 dimensions)**

**length of pred is 54626**

My question is I want to get the words with highest probability in each vector so that I can get to know by the words that why it predicted as positive or negative class. Therefore, how to get the words which have highest probability in each vector?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can get the importantance of each word out of the fit model by using the `coefs_` or `feature_log_prob_` attributes. For example

```
neg_class_prob_sorted = NB_optimal.feature_log_prob_[0, :].argsort()[::-1]
pos_class_prob_sorted = NB_optimal.feature_log_prob_[1, :].argsort()[::-1]

print(np.take(count_vect.get_feature_names(), neg_class_prob_sorted[:10]))
print(np.take(count_vect.get_feature_names(), pos_class_prob_sorted[:10]))
```

Prints the top 10 most predictive words for each of your classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was so helpful. You saved me.

Comment: I think `np.take(count_vect.get_feature_names(), neg_class_prob_sorted[:10])` returns the 10 least important features.

Comment: @piman314

print(np.take(count_vect.get_feature_names(), neg_class_prob_sorted[:10])) belongs to which class ?

also, can you please tell me, along with the feature names how can I print its corresponding probability value?

Comment: The `argsort` output needs to be reversed to get the most important features: `neg_class_prob_sorted = NB_optimal.feature_log_prob_[0, :].argsort()[::-1]`

Comment: The answer from @dimid is correct as well.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, **I disagree with the accepted answer, since they are outputting the conditional log probs**. For example (this is what actually happened to me and that's why I proposed a different approach), let's say you have a sentiment analysis with Naive Bayes and you use feature_log_prob_ as in the answer.
feature_log_prob_ of the word 'the' is Prob(the | y==1), since the word 'the' is really likely to occur, this will be considired an 'important feature'; but bear in mind that Prob(the | y==1) is also really likely (because the word 'the' occurs no matter if the sentiment is positive or negative). Therefore if you did not remove stopwords, this word will be more important than the word 'WORSE' for predicting a negative class in a sentiment classifier. This is clearly unintuitive and wrong. It happened to me in a project.

In case someone mentions that still the Prob(the | y==1) is high: Yes, the word 'the' helps to predict the positive class  since Prob(the | y==1)  is high, but it will equally help to predict the negative class and therefore has no effect (is not important).

**Proposed solution:**

I had the same trouble, maybe this is for datascience exchange forum but I want to post it here since I achieved a very good result.

First:

- Stands for positive class ,

- Stands for negative class.
  P() stands for proability.

We are going to build odds ratio, which can be demostrated that it is equal to
P(word i ,+) / P(word i ,-) (let me know if you need the demostration of it guys).
If this ratio is greater than 1 means that the word i is more likely to occur
in a positive texts than in negative text.

These are the priors in the naive bayes model:

```
# remember normalize=True outputs proportion 
prob_pos = df_train['y'].value_counts(normalize=True)[0]
prob_neg = df_train['y'].value_counts(normalize=True)[1]
```

Create a dataframe for storing the words

```
df_nbf = pd.DataFrame()
df_nbf.index = count_vect.get_feature_names()
# Convert log probabilities to probabilities. 
df_nbf['pos'] = np.e**(nb.feature_log_prob_[0, :])
df_nbf['neg'] = np.e**(nb.feature_log_prob_[1, :])

 
df_nbf['odds_positive'] = (df_nbf['pos']/df_nbf['neg'])*(prob_pos /prob_neg)

df_nbf['odds_negative'] = (df_nbf['neg']/df_nbf['pos'])*(prob_neg/prob_pos )
```

Most important words. This will give you a >1 ratio. For example a
odds_ratio_negative =2  for the word "damn" means that this word
is twice likely to occur when the comment or your class is negative in comparison with your positive class.

```
# Here are the top5 most important words of your positive class:
odds_pos_top5 = df_nbf.sort_values('odds_positive',ascending=False)['odds_positive'][:5]
# Here are the top5 most important words of your negative class:
odds_neg_top5 = df_nbf.sort_values('odds_negative',ascending=False)['odds_negative'][:5]
```

Comment: The other answers does not give you var importance since this is the log of the Prob( word / + ) for example. And for example the word "the "  has a very high  probability for positive class as well as for negative class. Therefore both in the naive bayes weight the same. and could be treated as a constant ( it means it does not change the prob of being of one class or another)

Comment: Thanks, an interesting approach. Shouldn't we use e instead of 10 for exponentiation in `df_nbf['pos']`?

Comment: Hi,  you are raising a very valid point. I have read sklearn documentation and they don't say anything about what log transformation they are using. I've got very interesting results using 10 exponenciation  and assumed that sklearn were using log10 transformation for the probabilities. Please let me know if I am wrong. 
To clarify to the readers the order of the var importance is unlikely to change, but the interpretation that I have stated  would change if I am not using the right transformation.

Comment: Looking at the source code I saw `np.lop` and not `np.log10`.

Comment: Very late to the party, but I think many people are still looking for this: This answer, although not that beautiful, really is the one on point. When people ask about important features in a binary classification task, they typically want the features most predictive of the class. All the other answers (and all others I have seen elsewhere) don't actually give you the those most informative features. For instance, features appearing in all documents should be uninformative, but will have a high feature importance, according to the other answers

Comment: @JBN , yeah,  according to sklearn documentation,  feature_log_prob_ndarray is just ln(Prob(xi / class=k )  , so the fact that a word is present very present in one class does not imply that it wion't be present in the other class, what matters after all is the words that are more present in  one class instead of the other one

Comment: @Tom - This is actually a great way to explain word importance. Could you please enlighten on how this calculations would change if you had three classes or more than two classes? Will the denominator change like `df_nbf['odds_positive'] = (nb.feature_log_prob_[0, :])/(nb.feature_log_prob_[1, :] + nb.feature_log_prob[2,:])*(prob_0/(prob_1+prob_2))` ? Also, why are you multiplying the ratio of class probabilities where you already individual class probabilities i.e. `prob_pos` and `prob_neg`?

Comment: Sorry Krishnang, I'm late, yes you are correct the idea would be kind of one-versus-rest classifie logic, as you are mentioning but see my adjusted answer. What you are doing with your equation is creating the probability of 'other class' . 
Secondly, why am I multiplying the ratio of class probaiblites? See it for your self in the docs, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html  (see method feature_log_prob , what you have is not the individidual class probabilities. Instead you have the conditional probabilities as stated in the documentation.

Comment: The expression I got is Prob(word i positive class) / Prob (word i , negative class) ; and that's why I needed to multiply the conditional probaiblities by prob_pos/prob_neg . Why ? Because the interpretation would be really nice: Prob(word i positive class) / Prob (word i , negative class)  = 5  for example is telling you that the word_i is 5 times likely to occur in the positive class than in the negative class.

Comment: If you want to think it  in other way: prob_pos/prob_neg is JUST a constant and thus the rank of the importance will not change, but bear in mind but if you do that, the interpretation WILL change.

Answer (score 4):

```
def get_salient_words(nb_clf, vect, class_ind):
    """Return salient words for given class
    Parameters
    ----------
    nb_clf : a Naive Bayes classifier (e.g. MultinomialNB, BernoulliNB)
    vect : CountVectorizer
    class_ind : int
    Returns
    -------
    list
        a sorted list of (word, log prob) sorted by log probability in descending order.
    """

    words = vect.get_feature_names()
    zipped = list(zip(words, nb_clf.feature_log_prob_[class_ind]))
    sorted_zip = sorted(zipped, key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)

    return sorted_zip

neg_salient_top_20 = get_salient_words(NB_optimal, count_vect, 0)[:20]
pos_salient_top_20 = get_salient_words(NB_optimal, count_vect, 1)[:20]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
pred_proba = NB_optimal.predict_proba(X_test)
words = np.take(count_vect.get_feature_names(), pred_proba.argmax(axis=1))
```

Comment: It is not clear how your answer will return the most important features as per the classifier. Your code selects the feature names with indices that correspond to the class with the highest probability for each test input, i.e. indices from [0, n_classes-1], and those indices need not be related to the most important features at all. Also,  it should be possible to determine the importance of various features right after training (fit / fit_transform) and shouldn't need the test data at all. Shouldn't the indices be chosen based on feature_log_prob_ as mentioned in other answers?