# Getting feature importance in Naive bayes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, naivebayes

My problem is exactly similar to this, 
[How to get feature Importance in naive bayes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526898/how-to-get-feature-importance-in-naive-bayes)

but when I run the code

```
neg_class_prob_sorted = NB_optimal.feature_log_prob_[0, :].argsort()
pos_class_prob_sorted = NB_optimal.feature_log_prob_[1, :].argsort()

print(np.take(count_vect.get_feature_names(), neg_class_prob_sorted[:10]))
print(np.take(count_vect.get_feature_names(), pos_class_prob_sorted[:10]))
```

it always prints words with same initials

```
['aafco' 'misfit' 'misfir' 'miseri' 'miser' 'misconcept' 'miscarriag'
 'misc' 'mirin' 'minuscul']
['aafco' 'metrx' 'meticul' 'methood' 'metaplus' 'metaphor' 'mestemach'
 'messiest' 'mesmer' 'mesa']
```

Is there any better way I can print the important features corrosponding to positive and negative class?

Comment: Post more details about your dataset, problem and full code. Is this something like yes, no problem?

Answer (score 0):

important_features= pd.DataFrame(data=np.transpose(model.fit(fdata, y_train).feature_log_prob_).astype("float32"),index=fdata.columns)

Comment: Please follow rules of StackOverflow while leaving response. Thank you